# innerHTML for character reference in attribute value is not preserved as escaped secuence. Any way to workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I put such code to Firefox:

```
<div id="my">
    <div title="&lt;b&gt; title &lt;/b&gt;">&lt;b&gt; text &lt;/b&gt;</div>
</div>
```

After evaluation of:

```
document.getElementById("my").innerHTML
```

I got:

```
"<div title="<b> title </b>">&lt;b&gt; text &lt;/b&gt;</div>"
```

As you can see title attribute is damaged... Is this a bug?

Link to playground: http://jsfiddle.net/uGXQP/

**UPDATE** I run tests under Firefox and Opera - it reproduced. On Chrome it work as expected.

**UPDATE 2** I found this issue then work with http://code.google.com/p/canvg/ project. It have main routine which require SVG as string as input argument. Natural way to do so is to use **innerHTML**...

So this library parse DOM as string and can't handle properly **<>** chars it stream in attribute value...

Comment: Why would you need that? It's not XML, it's HTML.

Comment: Try an XMLSerializer: http://jsfiddle.net/uGXQP/1/

Answer (score 3):

The `innerHTML` property does not, in general, give you the markup in an HTML source document. Instead, it performs a serialization of the content of the element in the DOM. There is no standard on this yet, but the HTML5 CR specifies rules for [serializing HTML fragments](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#serializing-html-fragments), and the [DOM Parsing and Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/) WD defines `innerHTML` in terms of such serialization. This means that many parts of markup will be canonicalized, and this includes the principle that within an attribute value, the character “<” appears as such. If it was written as `&lt;` in HTML, it had been converted to “<” during parsing – the DOM does not have information about the original syntax used to represent “<”. Unfortunately, some browsers get this wrong.

Anyway, if you want an attribute value to contain the four characters `&lt;`, you need to write them so that the ampersand has been escaped: `&amp;lt;`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't a bug. The two ways to express the attribute value are equivalent (since `&` has special meaning inside attribute values, but `<` does not). It hasn't been damaged, it has just been expressed differently.

If you want to store an `&` character in an attribute value, do so as `&amp;`.

If you want to get an attribute value, do so with `element.getAttribute`.

Comment: Seems that you are right, but I still can't find this statement in W3C HTML/DOM standards... My main issue - that parser of external library can't work with such **innerHTML** output... +1